# Withdrawing from after tax 401k rollovers to Roth IRA

Tags: united-states, 401k, roth-ira, withdrawal, rollover

I have after tax contribution. I have setup Roth in plan conversation. If I rollover that money to a Roth IRA, which I can do since it is after-tax money. Do I have to wait for 5 years to withdraw my contributions from Roth IRA without penalty or incurring additional tax?

https://www.kitces.com/blog/understanding-the-two-5-year-rules-for-roth-ira-contributions-and-conversions/

Comment: Is the 401(k) money post-tax contributions or are they Roth contributions? They are different things.

Comment: Just be sure that you can withdraw _only_ the after-tax contributions to a Traditional 401(k) from the 401(k) plan in order to roll that money over into a Roth IRA.

Comment: @DilipSarwate: Withdrawals and conversions from Traditional 401(k) are subject to the pro-rata rule, so you can't withdraw or convert only the after-tax amounts if there are pre-tax amounts (including earnings). But you can split a rollover so that after-tax amounts go to Roth IRA and pre-tax amounts go to Traditional IRA.

Comment: @user102008 Thanks, and yes, I know about the pro-rata stuff.

Comment: @mhoran it is after tax

Comment: @AravindT: You mean an after-tax contribution to a Traditional 401(k) (i.e. non-Roth 401(k))? Those are uncommon these days.

Comment: @AravindT: Also, what do you mean by "I have setup Roth in plan conversation"? Do you mean you are doing an in-plan conversion from Traditional 401(k) to Roth 401(k)? And then you are doing a rollover from Roth 401(k) to Roth IRA?